# Recursive function prints garbage value while printing the else statement and not printing the value in if statement

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void recusive(int sum){
if(sum<=10)
{
    sum=sum+recusive(sum+1);
    printf("%d",sum);
}
else
{
    printf("it's greater then 10");
}
}
main()
{
int a=0;
recusive(a);
}
```

this prints the else value only and I don't understand why?
and it prints *it's greater than 10 and some garbage values when I use printf function in if statements*
Anyone explain this

Comment: You don't return anything from it so that's why... Now go enable compiler warnings.

Comment: Actually the braces don't match so this won't even compile.

Comment: And `main` *must* be declared to return an `int` (but the actual `return` statement may be omitted, but *only* for the `main` function).

Comment: it's still prints some gurbage values

Comment: Even after adding the missing curly-brace, your code should still not compile. What does `recursive` ***return***?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a new line (\n) at the end of your printf, you'll be able to see there are more than 1 line. (there is one missing closing brace before "main" too).

The code becomes the following:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int recusive(int sum){
    if(sum<=10)
    {
        sum=sum+recusive(sum+1);
        printf("%d\n",sum);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("it's greater then 10\n");
    }
    return sum ;

}

int main()
{
    int a=0;
    recusive(a);
}
```

And the output is as expected:

```
it's greater then 10
21
30
38
45
51
56
60
63
65
66
66
```

And you may want to see the cumulated sum while adding it up (i.e. before calling recursively the function) rather than displaying the results after hitting the stop condition of the recursivity (i.e. while going down the call stack afterward). With the following code:

```
    int recusive(int sum){
        if(sum<=10)
        {
            printf("%d\n",sum);
            sum=sum+recusive(sum+1);
            
        }
        else
        {
            printf("it's greater then 10\n");
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

You get the following output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
it's greater then 10
```

Comment: I strongly recommend adding `return` somewhere in `recursive()`

Comment: @Jean-Loup Sabatier yes it's printing like that why is the question in this post

Comment: Yes, there should be a return (I added it by editing my post).  @Muneesh: This is printing like that because you're calling the recursivity first and then displaying sum+<random return value because you didn't called return>